# How to capture Key Down event from Parent view to Child View in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, prism, key-bindings

I want to capture the Key Down(for ex., CTRL+N) in the main window, into the child control. 
Currently I am trying with the KeyTrigger using expression blend api.
If there is any other way to do it without using expression blend, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Use the UIElement.KeyDown event?

Comment: @EmperorAiman. I need to capture Parent view KeyDown event in the child view when the child view is not in the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PreviewKeyDown event.  It is a tunneling event and starts from the source and makes its way down the logical tree.

Comment: PreviewKeyDown didn't work. Using the Expression Blend API.